# Using Laravel to query table while grouping and averaging

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table called assessment_data:
[image: assessment_data table screenshot]

It gathers the assessed_level for a given room/assessment id/subject/unit/outcome of a series of students in a specific subject.

This is my Laravel query:

```
$assessment_tally_levels = DB::table('assessment_data')
    ->join('subjects', 'assessment_data.subject_id', '=', 'subjects.id')
    ->select('subjects.short_name as Subject', 'assessment_data.assessed_level as Level', DB::raw('count(*) as Students'))
    ->where('assessment_data.user_id', Auth::id()) 
    ->where('assessment_data.room_id', $room_id)
    ->whereBetween('assessment_data.created_at', [$current_term->term_start." 00:00:01", $current_term->term_end." 23:59:59"])
    ->orderByRaw('assessment_data.assessed_level ASC')
    ->groupBy('assessment_data.subject_id')
    ->groupBy('assessment_data.assessed_level')
    ->get()
    ->toJson();
```

What I am getting as a JSON output is this:

> [{"Subject":"Science","Level":1,"Students":16},{"Subject":"Phys
>   Ed","Level":1,"Students":1},{"Subject":"Math","Level":1,"Students":1},{"Subject":"ELA","Level":1,"Students":2},{"Subject":"Art","Level":2,"Students":1},{"Subject":"Science","Level":2,"Students":23},{"Subject":"CTF","Level":2,"Students":1},{"Subject":"Math","Level":2,"Students":3},{"Subject":"ELA","Level":2,"Students":3},{"Subject":"Phys
>   Ed","Level":2,"Students":3},{"Subject":"Phys
>   Ed","Level":3,"Students":3},{"Subject":"Art","Level":3,"Students":1},{"Subject":"Science","Level":3,"Students":40},{"Subject":"Health","Level":3,"Students":4},{"Subject":"CTF","Level":3,"Students":4},{"Subject":"Math","Level":3,"Students":4},{"Subject":"ELA","Level":3,"Students":4},{"Subject":"Phys
>   Ed","Level":4,"Students":4},{"Subject":"Science","Level":4,"Students":41},{"Subject":"Art","Level":4,"Students":4},{"Subject":"Health","Level":4,"Students":2},{"Subject":"CTF","Level":4,"Students":1},{"Subject":"Math","Level":4,"Students":4},{"Subject":"ELA","Level":4,"Students":3}]

The problem is no class has 40 students in it (as is otherwise indicated in the Science Level 3 line above).

Here is a link to the full dataset from the example above (wasn't sure how else to share this data with you):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1swc9AVLp0ZVDJw3UntgpSDQTSB2MaSunVul7zR0kNf8/edit?usp=sharing

I need to be grouping the students together by their student_id and averaging all of that student's assessed_levels for a subject together to get a single tally for the student.

How might I do this?

Comment: What are your eloquent relationships like on your `Student` model? The reason I am asking is that this sort of query would be much easier if you could do something like `Students:all()->with('assessments.results')->groupBy('assessments.subject.shortname');`

Comment: Try `count(distinct student_id) as Students`.

Comment: @Spholt - I should probably really brush up on my Eloquent skills. Anytime a query has ventured past one-to-one, I have simply moved into Query Builder for simplicity sake (at the onset). The query you provided does look nice. There are only two tables in this specific instance—one for housing the assessment data and one for housing subject names. I am guessing it wouldn't be too difficult to set that up using Eloquent...?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir - that has done the job of grouping the students together. Is there a way to round up/down the students who have anything other than a whole number, so they are lumped into the same 4 whole number tiers (1, 2, 3, and 4) as the other students? Right now I have a couple kids who are a '2.87', '3.25', and '3.4'. I would like for them to be rounded to a '3', '3', and '3,' respectively. (Sorry, I know that's outside the scope of this OP.

Comment: Can post the query that calculates the average?

Comment: Cancel that request. Can you please post your answer, @JonasStaudenmeir. That was the solution. :)

Comment: @SheldonScott glad to see you got it working :). If you prefer using the query builder then by all means go for it but i would suggest taking a look at the Laravel docs for the Eloquent ORM (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships), it is well worth spending the time to understand some of the other relationships available as it is the most powerful aspect of Laravel, at least in my opinion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you are calculating the number of assessments.

You have to count the individual students:

```
DB::raw('count(distinct student_id) as Students')
```